# Can't accept String or Integer?

Tags: c#, string

My problem is can't insert a value to my database because CATEGORY is a of type InsuranceCategory that is read only.So it will not accept a string or an integer.. What would I suppose to do this issue to be able to accept a string or an integer?

```
        Insurance oInsurance = new Insurance();
        oInsurance.Category.Value = drpCategory.SelectedValue;   

        HCSInsurance oHCSInsurance = new HCSInsurance();
        oHCSInsurance.CreateInsurance(oInsurance);
```

Much thanks!

Comment: We'll need the code for InsuranceCategory too. Is it an enum or a class?

Comment: Hey, can you explain better your problem? I believe your code doesn't explain the problem... What is "read-only"? Category.Value property? Insurance.Category? Thanks.

Comment: Since its readonly you can't assign the property, check if it allows the same in the constructor

Comment: @V4Vendetta, what do you mean?

Comment: I think he meant the same thing I said in my answer.

Comment: yes, it allows the same constructor..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this work at all?

```
oInsurance.Category = new InsuranceCategory(drpCategory.SelectedValue)
```

Comment: Error 11 'HSIInsurance.InsuranceCategory' does not contain a constructor that takes '1' arguments

Comment: It was just a guess based on the common way to develop readonly values. We really need to see the definition of HSIInsurance.InsuranceCategory.